# Meaning of expression "Carry a card"

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of *carry a card* in this context?

> Mary Webster's Sarah's carried a card for years, so's everybody's cook in this town.

The place is the American South (Alabama). Sarah was a black cook. The time is from the 1940s to the 1950's. I've searched the net, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Hi Isabel,  Where is this quote from?

Comment: The quote is from "Go Set a Watchman" by Harper Lee.

Comment: Could you provide some more of the context (the preceding paragraphs)? It’s not clear from that sentence alone what type of card it’s talking about.

Comment: Would it have been a card that entitled her to certain privileges normally reserved to whites at that time?

Comment: I might have understood it. It's probably a member card of the NAACP, meaning they belonged to it. At least it's the best meaning in the context. Thank you all for your interest.

Comment: It's some sort of id card, of course, and apparently all the black cooks had them, but it's impossible to tell what sort of card without some "domain-specific knowledge".  My guess, from the (very meager) context, would be a sort of admission card to allow entry to a whites-only grocery store or some such.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps from **[card-carrying](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/card-carrying)**

> **card-carrying:**
>
> 1. Registered as a member of a political party or trade union:
>      *'a card-carrying communist'*
> 2. often humorous Confirmed in or dedicated to a specified pursuit or outlook:
>      *'a card-carrying hippie'*

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  "Card-carrying" comes from "carrying a card", not the other way around.

Comment: In this case, it kind of does.  The character was a member of the NAACP -- she was a "card-carrying member", therefore she carried the card, like every (white) person's (black) cook.